# Code-coverage in branches with different endianess

Tags: c, code-coverage, endianness

Assume you have some code like:

```
if (endianness == ENDIAN_LITTLE)
{
  // Do little-endian code here
}
else
{
  // Do big-endian code here
}
```

Are there some good patterns on how to cover both branches with some unit-tests on the same system (either bit- or little-endian)?

Comment: http://commandcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: I try to handle all of the endianness in one module and make the rest of the code unaware that there is such a thing.  But my application lends itself to that.  If you already have a large application with this kind of code sprinkled though it then I don't have an answer just yet.

Comment: Just use macros for endianess when reading to/from file or network. Then you do not have to give a monkeys in the rest of the code. Therefore the problem you think you are questioning about does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
long some_number;
memcpy(&some_number, "\x01\x23\x45\x67", 4);
check(some_number, 0x1234567, ENDIAN_BIG);
memcpy(&some_number, "\x67\x45\x23\x01", 4);
check(some_number, 0x1234567, ENDIAN_LITTLE);
```

WARNING: this is probably undefined behaviour (i'd have to check the standard which i'm too lazy to do now), because it relies heavily on a) a long having 4 bytes and b) what happens during pointer casts. However, if the compiler doesn't choose to optimize UD out completely, this will do what you expect it to do. If it works, you're ok, if it doesn't work, it might still be due to the compiler's behaviour.